# Should biomedical engineering/ biotech academics aim to start businesses?

Tags: ethics, engineering, biology, biotechnology

in my relatively short academic career, I've gathered that academic engineering seems to be more about creating ideas than actually iteratively improving a product using engineering methods. In my field, biomedical engineering, I worry that this is not enough because many biomedical ideas require immense funding that usually comes from large companies willing to wait a decade for profits, and thus good ideas are shelved (obviously many layers to this).

Many questions address how academics could make money, or start up companies, but my question is whether it is actually our responsibility to do so in the biomedical and biotech fields?

edit:
my assumption is that starting a business is the only way to get a product to customers. Answers that provide alternative strategies to achieve this ultimate goal are welcome :)

Comment: Good academics do not necessarily make good business people.

Comment: @Compass And nobody says you have to start a company alone. :-)

Comment: @earthling Yes, but starting a company is also a risky business, even with a business person to start it with. An [80% fail rate](http://www.forbes.com/sites/ericwagner/2013/09/12/five-reasons-8-out-of-10-businesses-fail/) is a terrifying prospect.

Answer (score 5):

The NIH seems to take the opposite view of you. The NIH provides funding for the training of a large number of biomedical engineers. The individual NRSA mechanism (F31 and F32) provides some of the most prestigious funding for PhD students and post docs. This funding comes with a pay back obligation such if you leave academia for industry within a few years of receiving NRSA funding, you can be required to pay back the funding. The NIH is in essence saying "do not leave academia" to the best biomedical engineers it trains. If the NIH thought more people should be starting up companies, I believe it would drastically increase the funding to the SBIR mechanism and rework the pay back mechanism to encourage individuals to leave instead of stay.

Comment: thanks for this informative comment. But leaving academia is not what I mean. I am more interested in how to translate research that deserves to be translated. Not necessarily by me, and the rights and money aren't my concern. rather, how can academics translate research while remaining in research?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly agree that it is ethically important for beneficial research (biomedical or otherwise) to be transitioned from the laboratory out into the world where it can benefit people.  It is not obvious to me, however, that leaving academia to found a startup is necessarily the best way in which to accomplish this, particularly for biomedical work.

There are two reasons that I see it this way:

1. The skills necessary to be a good academic researcher and the skills necessary to found a company are very different, and different again from the skills necessary to bring a safe and reliable product to a large market.
2. One of the reasons it takes so long to transition biomedical research is the difficulty of ensuring safety, given our current state of knowledge.  Yes, there are many other problems with market structure and regulatory frameworks, but fundamentally it is a lot more dangerous to put a drug or a medical device in somebody's body than to deploy an app on their smartphone, and a lot more difficult to evaluate safety than with a piece of consumer electronics.  One of the values that established companies bring to the table is experience with navigating these problems.

So I think there is a strong ethical responsibility to attempt to move one's research into application, but the right way to do that for a particular case may often not be a startup, but instead to seek out tech transfer relationships with other academics, entrepreneurs, companies and even funding agencies.

Comment: _I think there is a strong ethical responsibility to attempt to move one's research into application_ — Why?

Comment: @JeffE I also have no problem with inquiry that has no expected application.  Once you see potential for a beneficial application, however, I think that if you do *nothing* towards seeing if that application can be realized, then I think you assume some of the responsibility if those benefits do not come to pass.

Comment: @JeffE maybe because that is how academic research is sold to the taxpayers who fund it.

Comment: @CapeCode That suggests some ethical responsibility on those who sell it that way, then; not necessarily on those who are perfectly frank about their technology transfer plans (or lack thereof) in grant proposals.